# Is the affine hypersurface defined by ((xz+1)^2/z)-((yz+1)^3/z)+xyz=1 a "known" hypersurface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

The hypersurface $\lbrace (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}^3:\frac{(xz+1)^2}{z}-\frac{(yz+1)^3}{z}=1 \rbrace$ is a well-known example of a contractible hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^3$. See for instance, Example 2.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9801075.pdf

If I deform the above equation to $$((xz+1)^2/z)-((yz+1)^3/z)+ a\cdot xyz=1$$ I get a one parameter family of hypersurfaces which according to my computations are all smooth. Are the hypersurfaces which arise when $a \neq 0$ contractible as well? Are they known to play a role in the theory of these hypersurfaces?